# Como ler arquivo .sql com Java

Tags: java, mysql

Tenho uma consulta complexa em MySQL com `sub-select` e `joins`.

Gostaria de ler este script através de um arquivo `.sql` utilizando a linguagem do JPA/Hibernate (JPQL ou HQL), por exemplo `getSession().createQuery(arquivo.sql);`.

Ou outra forma que me permita ler o aquivo ser ter que ser chumbado o script no repositório. Isso é possível?

Answer (score 0):

```
String sqlString = path_to_file;
String sql = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(sqlString), "UTF-8");
getSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
```

Aproveitei e apliquei [*tranformers* do Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445092/hibernates-transformers-aliastobean-method) para tratar a informação e transformar num Dto.